# How to make the navigation bar title to scroll automatically if it is too long?

Tags: ios

For example, there is a navigation bar title named 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',it is too long to show it completely.So I want to let it show by scrolling. Is there has one method to make it successful?

Comment: https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel

Comment: You must custom it.

Comment: Thank you very much ,it is useful for me .